# How do I require a file or class in a vendor library in Yii2 that is not already included?

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2, google-ads-api

I have this class that Yii2 cannot see. All the other classes work. I tried the following. The commented lines did not work.

```
// use app\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\Api\Ads\Common\Util\ErrorUtils;
// require_once UTIL_PATH . '/ErrorUtils.php';
require_once('../vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util/ErrorUtils.php');
use \ErrorUtils;
```

This works, but it doesn't look right. Also it doesn't work in the command mode, which I need.

```
$ yii cron
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'require_once(../vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util/ErrorUtils.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/xxx/models/GoogleAdWords.php:36
```

How can I require or use this class in Yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that you use doesn't provide psr-4 autoloader settings for its classes. You need to add [autoload classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) for classes that you want to load, into your *composer.json* in project's root directory like following:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Lib",
      "vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util"
    ]
},
```

and then in your console: *composer [dump-autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload)*

This will update the composer autoloader. After that you'll be able to call library classes with: `\ErrorUtils::GetSourceOperationIndex($error)`

Comment: That worked! I tried adding the path in the Google library `composer.json`, but that only worked for the command line, not the web. I didn't know about adding to the root `composer.json` or `dump-autoload`.

Comment: It's the wrong place to do it. Never deal with your dependencies autoload in your OWN autoload section. Besides that, the library actually DOES provide autoloading, starting with version 5.4.0 - previous versions are broken and should be updated. If you have to add metadata to a package you use, add it in the "repositories" section as "type=package". It is not that easy for beginners to do it - raise an issue in the projects bug tracker instead to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt addto composer (shell command):

```
$ composer require googleads/googleads-php-lib
```

Then simply use te class:

```
\ErrorUtils::GetApiErrors($var);
```

Note that googleads don't use namespaces so it's "\" NS